# itextpdf pdf from mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, pdf, itext

i'm new in java, now i try to use itextpdf library, the code is: make a connection with mysql, run a query and get a byte object, now i need take these bytes to put on a page on mi pdf document.
the data on my database it's a pdf file on byte format, on mysql datatype is "long blob"

now i think need some like these code

```
byte[] bytes = null;

Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("\some\dir\file.pdf"));
document.open();

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "user", "pass");
PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT file FROM files");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
try {
while (rs.next()) {
bytes = rs.getBytes("file");

document.add(bytes);
document.close();
cn.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `bytes` consist of text that needs to be rendered inside the PDF, you need to replace the following line:

```
document.add(bytes);
```

With the following line:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(new String(bytes)));
```

You may experience encoding problems if `bytes` contains special characters, but let's solve this problem one step at a time.

If the `bytes` are a full and valid PDF file, you need to feed them to a `PdfReader` object:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
```

What happens next totally depends on what you want to do with the PDF file. If you just need to serve the PDF, then obviously you don't need iText at all. If you want to copy specific pages or combine that file with other files, then you need to use `PdfCopy`. If you want to stamp extra data on the file (a watermark, page numbers,...), you need `PdfStamper`. Read [Chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book to find out what you can do, and look at table 6.1 to make sure you select the right class.

Yet a better idea is to use iText 7 instead of iText 5. In that case, you need to read the chapter [Manipulating an existing PDF document](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) and [Reusing existing PDF documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) of the iText 7 jump-start tutorial.

Comment: **thanks for response**, "new Paragraph" take the metadata and print a string of characters, im looking some similar to a _image class_  because var _bytes already contains a pdf file_, so i need inject these bytes (pdf file) on document page

Comment: In that case, your question was not clear. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok the way to solve for now it's these code,thanks @Bruno

```
    byte[] bytes = null;

Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("\some\dir\file.pdf"));
document.open();

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "user", "pass");
PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT file FROM files");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
try {
while (rs.next()) {
bytes = rs.getBytes("file");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
PdfImportedPage page;
page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
document.add(image);
document.newPage();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```